# Eclipse Crti.o and Crt1.o cannot find

Tags: linux, eclipse, gcc, linaro

I build sample code with cross compile *linaro*. I have two situations

**Situation 1**:

I download `gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf` from linaro website and extract it to path `/home/xxx/opt/toolchains`. I also

```
export
PATH=$PATH:/home/xxx/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin
```

Then i use eclipse for testing some simple example codes with Cross Settings `/home/xxx/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin`. But when i compile, i get this error.

```
/home/xxx/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld:
cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/home/xxx/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/5.5.0/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld:
cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
```

I found and know that crti.o and crt1.o in `/home/xxx/opt/toolchains/gcc-linaro-5.5.0-2017.10-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc/usr/lib`.

**Situation 2**:

When i follow another way. The first, i install

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Then in eclipse path of `Cross Settings` i config `/usr/bin/` and build. Everything is OK.

So with situation 1, How I setup correctly in Eclipse? Thank for your support.

Comment: I'm having a very similar problem with Eclipse and cross-compilation (from a Windows environment/mingw to a Linux 2.6.x ARM environment). Crt1.o not found. Did you fix your problem?

Comment: @Adrien: check your libraries include files *.so and files symbol link. maybe some file broken.

Comment: @Adrien Look into these potential areas. --dynamic-linker, --sysroot, make sure that you are linking with ld and not gcc